# Regular expression to split a string into 5 parts as below

Tags: java, regex

This is my input string and I wanted to break it up into 5 parts according to regex below so that I can print out the 5 groups but I always get a no match found. What am I doing wrong ?

```
String content="beit Be it enacted by the Senate and House of Representatives of the United States of America in Congress assembled,,&lt;m&gt;Surface Transportation Extension Act of 2012.,&lt;xm&gt;";

Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(&lt;m&gt;)(.*)(&lt;xm&gt;)(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(regEx.matcher(content).group(1));
System.out.println(regEx.matcher(content).group(2));
System.out.println(regEx.matcher(content).group(3));
System.out.println(regEx.matcher(content).group(4));
System.out.println(regEx.matcher(content).group(5));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(&lt;m&gt;)(.*)(&lt;xm&gt;)(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = regEx.matcher(content);
if (matcher.find()) { // calling find() is important
// if the regex matches multiple times, use while instead of if
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
} else {
    System.out.println("Regex didn't match");
}
```

Comment: jlordo, I ultimately want to do this: "regEx.matcher(content).replaceAll(replaceExpression)" and my replaceExpression is like: "$1&lt;marginal&gt;$3&lt;/marginal&gt;$5" but it doesnt replace.

Comment: @Phoenix: and where's the problem? You didn't address that in your question at all.

Comment: @jlordo: he asked a first question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903315/why-doesnt-the-following-regex-work-when-input-through-spring), but didn't have an answer for 50 minutes (gasp!), so he asked another.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex's 5th match doesn't match anything - there is no content after the `&lt;xm&gt;`. Also, you should really run `regEx.matcher()` once, and then pull the groups out of the one matcher; as written, it executes the regex 5 times, once to get each group out. Also your RegEx is never executed unless you call `find()` or `matches`.

Comment: it actually executes the regex never, becaue neither `find()` nor `matches()` is ever called.

Comment: `find()` and `matches()` can't be called on a `Pattern`.